# WPF Radio Buttons

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button

I am creating Radio button on Visual Studio and I am having a trouble with Binding

This is my button:

```
<RadioButton VericalAlignment="Center" GroupName="group1" Content="name"></RadioButton>
```

I want that if the button was selected then the value of {"someString " + Content Value} will be bind
to SomeClass.variable

is something like this possible?
Thank you!

Comment: Handle the `Checked` event?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowRadioButton.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowRadioButton"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid Margin="81,36,-81,-36">
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="111,135,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Name="myRadioButton" Checked="myRadioButton_Checked"/>
</Grid>
```

CS file:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflowRadioButton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public string someVariable;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void myRadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            someVariable = "someString " + myRadioButton.IsChecked;
        }
    }
}
```